# What's the difference if you use a "+" or no "+" in outputting?

Tags: c#, string, text

```
Div1.InnerHtml = (someString);
```

-VS-

```
Div1.InnerHtml += (someString);
```

I notice they both do the same thing, but is there any real difference whether I have the `+` in there or not?
Also.. What's the difference between `InnerText` & `InnerHtml`?

Comment: dont forget to mark answre as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+=` will append `(someString)` to the existing value of `Div1.InnerHtml`, whereas `=` will *replace* the value of `Div1.InnerHtml` with `(someString)`.

If the results are the same then the starting value of `Div1.InnerHtml` is likely `null` or `string.Empty` (`""`)

Regarding `InnerText` vs `InnerHtml`:  `InnerHtml` might return something like `<h1>Hello World</h1>` whereas `InnerText` would return `Hello World` (the value of the element without the actual HTML element).

Consider these cases:

```
string someString = "Hello";
string innerHtml = "";

innerHtml += someString; // result will be "Hello"
```

---

```
string someString = "Hello";
string innerHtml = "";

innerHtml = someString; // result will be "Hello"
```

---

```
string someString = "Hello";
string innerHtml = "World";

innerHtml += someString; // result will be "HelloWorld"
```

---

```
string someString = "Hello";
string innerHtml = "World";

innerHtml = someString; // result will be "Hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

**Answer of first question**

[C# String Append](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-append)
-: += append string with the existing string

other example is

```
string s = "abc";
s+="cde";

output
s = "abcde"
```

**Answer of second question**

innerText will retrieve the value as it, though if it contains the  tags, it will render the text as it is, where as innerHTML retrives the values by applying the HTML tags if any.

Answer (score 2):

They are *not* the same thing at all. This is about strings manipulation and not something specific and related to ASP.NET

The first puts someString in the string property InnerHtml of Div1,

The second sets InnerHtml to be InnerHtml +(someString), so if, for example InnerHtml contained the string "aa" before this operation, it'll become "aaSomeString" at the later case, and "SomeString" at the former case.

Answer (score 1):

They're only doing the same thing because Div1 is empty when you do +=

+= is appending so if you did that a few times in a row you would see that you're getting data you may not have expected.

The assignment operator (=) will simply set the value of Div1 to whatever's on the left regardless of what was there previously.

Answer (score 1):

1. `+=` is concatenation (shortform for a = a + b)

   `=` will overwrite the value with the new one on the righthand side
2. `innerHtml` will allow you to add tags like `<p>` and `div`

   `innerText` will encode those tags as `&lt;p&gt;` and `&lt;div&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is a **shorthand operator**

for e.g.

```
i = i + (some value) and i+=(some value) both is same.
```

So, in general term,

```
Left_Val (operator)= right_val and Left_Val = Left_Val (operator) right_val are same
```

Please note that **operator** should be binary. **shorthand operators** cannot be used with unary (like **unary minus**) and ternary operator(like **?:**).